# Object expected Microsoft Jscript Runtime Error- Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node JS and I am getting Object expected at line number 1 Microsoft Jscript Runtime Error while running the code

```
var fs = require('fs');

function FileObject () {
this.filename = null;
this.exists = function(callback) {
var self = this;
fs.open(this.filename, 'r', function(err, handle){
if(err){
console.log(self.filename+  'does Not exist');
callback(false);
}
else {
console.log(self.filename+ 'does Exist Indeed');
callback(true);
fs.close(handle);
}
});
};
}
var fo = new FileObject();
fo.filename = 'doesnotexist';
fo.exists(function(does_it_exist) {
console.log('results from exists:' + does_it_exist);
});
```

Comment: *How* are you running this script?

Comment: I've tried to run the code from command prompt

Comment: Can you show exactly how you tried to execute your script from the command line?

Comment: e:\Bckup\D\TCS\Node\MarkNodeLiveLessons>"solve the problem.js"

- This command didn't work

When I tried the command- 
e:\Bckup\D\TCS\Node\MarkNodeLiveLessons>node "solve the problem.js"

I gt the output..

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't double-click the source file to run it, you need to execute the script from the command line (e.g. `C:\> node foo\bar.js` assuming your script `bar.js` is in `C:\foo`).

Comment: I am getting this error even while executing the code from the command prompt.

Comment: kindly don't copy and paset the answer, which is already answered by someone.

Comment: @PushpSingh What are you referring to? My answer was not "copy and pasted" from *anywhere*. Also, this answer was left 7 months *before* the only other answer submitted here as of this writing, so it's not even a "copy" of that answer.

Answer (score 14):

`node.js` file name is reserved in NodeJS. I too got the same error. I renamed my file to "test.js" and it worked...

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World OKKK");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

command prompt> `node test.js`

URL => http://localhost:8888 and it prints "Hello World OKKKK" on the browser.

Comment: all my internets to you sir